# Error making an insert to mysql from VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

This was working ok but suddenly it stopped to work and started to give me this error, either inserting new data or updating.
I must say that I know is bad to concatenate but our tachers obligates us do it this way.

I tried the same query in navicat and it works, but, when i put it in VB.net it start to give me this error.

Query code:

```
UPDATE personal SET nombre = '" & ModUser_txtNombre.Text & "', 2nombre = '" & ModUser_txt2Nombre.Text & "', apellido = '" & ModUser_txtApellido.Text & "', 2apellido = '" & ModUser_txt2apellido.Text & "', sexo = '" & ModUser_cbSexo.Text & "', f_nac = '" & ModUser_dateFNacimiento.Text & "', calle = '" & ModUser_txtDirCalle.Text & "', numero = " & ModUser_txtDirNumero.Text & ", estado_civil = '" & ModUser_cbEstCivil.Text & "', email = '" & ModUser_txtEmail.Text & "', hijos = '" & ModUser_txtHijos.Text & "', tel_celular = " & ModUser_txtCelular.Text & ", tel_fijo = " & ModUser_txtFijo.Text & ", f_ingreso = '" & ModUser_dateFIngreso.Text & "', cargo = " & cargo.ToString & ", grado = " & ModUser_cbGrado.Text & ", departamento = " & departamento.ToString & ", email_empr = '" & ModUser_txtMailEmpresarial.Text & "', tlf_empr = " & ModUser_txtTlfEmpresarial.Text & ", rol = " & rol.ToString & " WHERE doc = " & List_txtBuscar.Text & "(now insert)    

    insert into Personal (rol, doc, nombre, apellido, passwd, sexo, f_nac, 
                          estado_civil, f_ingreso, cargo, grado, dpto, email,
                           email_empr, tlf_empr, calle, numero, 2nombre,
                           2apellido, activo,) 
values(" & adduser_rol & ", " & AddUser_txtDocumento.Text & ", '" 
  & AddUser_txtNombre.Text & "', '" & AddUser_txtApellido.Text & "', " 
  & AddUser_txtContraseña.Text & ", '" & AddUser_cbSexo.Text & "', '" 
  & AddUser_dateFNacimiento.Text & "', '" & AddUser_cbEstCivil.Text & "', '" 
  & AddUser_dateFIngreso.Text & "', '" & AddUser_txtCargo.Text & "', " 
  & AddUser_cbGrado.Text & ", '" & AddUser_txtDepartamento.Text & "', '" 
  & AddUser_txtEmail.Text & "', '" & AddUser_txtMailEmpresarial.Text & "', " 
  & AddUser_txtTlfEmpresarial.Text & ", '" & AddUser_txtDirCalle.Text & "', " 
  & AddUser_txtDirNumero.Text & ", '" & 
     AddUser_txt2Nombre.Text & "', '" & AddUser_txt2apellido.Text & "', 's')
```

Code in visual:

```
   cnn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "UPDATE personal SET nombre = '" & ModUser_txtNombre.Text & "', 2nombre = '" & ModUser_txt2Nombre.Text & "', apellido = '" & ModUser_txtApellido.Text & "', 2apellido = '" & ModUser_txt2apellido.Text & "', sexo = '" & ModUser_cbSexo.Text & "', f_nac = '" & ModUser_dateFNacimiento.Text & "', calle = '" & ModUser_txtDirCalle.Text & "', numero = " & ModUser_txtDirNumero.Text & ", estado_civil = '" & ModUser_cbEstCivil.Text & "', email = '" & ModUser_txtEmail.Text & "', hijos = '" & ModUser_txtHijos.Text & "', tel_celular = " & ModUser_txtCelular.Text & ", tel_fijo = " & ModUser_txtFijo.Text & ", f_ingreso = '" & ModUser_dateFIngreso.Text & "', cargo = " & cargo.ToString & ", grado = " & ModUser_cbGrado.Text & ", departamento = " & departamento.ToString & ", email_empr = '" & ModUser_txtMailEmpresarial.Text & "', tlf_empr = " & ModUser_txtTlfEmpresarial.Text & ", rol = " & rol.ToString & " WHERE doc = " & List_txtBuscar.Text & ""
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Query, cnn)
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        cnn.Close()
```

(now insert)

```
Dim adduser_rol As Integer

        If AddUser_rbAdmin.Checked Then
            adduser_rol = 1
        ElseIf AddUser_rbUsuario.Checked Then
            adduser_rol = 2
        Else
            MsgBox("Debe seleccionar si el nuevo empleado es usuario o administrador.")
        End If
        Dim cnn As New MySqlConnection
        cnn.ConnectionString = ("data source=localhost;user id=root; password='1234';database=tax")
        Try
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "insert into Personal (rol, doc, nombre, apellido, passwd, sexo, f_nac, estado_civil, f_ingreso, cargo, grado, dpto, email, email_empr, tlf_empr, calle, numero, 2nombre, 2apellido, activo,) values(" & adduser_rol & ", " & AddUser_txtDocumento.Text & ", '" & AddUser_txtNombre.Text & "', '" & AddUser_txtApellido.Text & "', " & AddUser_txtContraseña.Text & ", '" & AddUser_cbSexo.Text & "', '" & AddUser_dateFNacimiento.Text & "', '" & AddUser_cbEstCivil.Text & "', '" & AddUser_dateFIngreso.Text & "', '" & AddUser_txtCargo.Text & "', " & AddUser_cbGrado.Text & ", '" & AddUser_txtDepartamento.Text & "', '" & AddUser_txtEmail.Text & "', '" & AddUser_txtMailEmpresarial.Text & "', " & AddUser_txtTlfEmpresarial.Text & ", '" & AddUser_txtDirCalle.Text & "', " & AddUser_txtDirNumero.Text & ", '" & AddUser_txt2Nombre.Text & "', '" & AddUser_txt2apellido.Text & "', 's', )"
            cnn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, cnn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Usuario guardado")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

And in both when I press the button it gives me the following errors:

> Updating Unknown column 'i' in 'field list'

Inserting
..."for the right syntax to use near')values(X,XXXXXXXX, 'XXXX', 'XXXX', XXXXXXXX, 'XXXXXX', 'XXXX-XX-XX','c' at line 1
(being X any value possible)

Table "Personal" desing:

[image: 1]

Comment: Is is possible that one of the fields being inserted contains an apostrophe?

Comment: Yikes, this will be scary-vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Comment: Also, I noticed the last line of the first part of the `INSERT` statement, which looks like this: `2apellido, activo,) `. That trailing comma is not correct.

Comment: I solved the issue in the INSERT but I don't know what is happening in the UPDATE, i think it is correct and also I tried it directly in MySQL and works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You sql statement is wrong. At the end of the columns list you have an comma too much

```
 Query = "insert into Personal (rol, doc, nombre, apellido, passwd, sexo, f_nac
    , estado_civil, f_ingreso, cargo, grado, dpto, email, email_empr, tlf_empr
    , calle, numero, 2nombre, 2apellido, activo) values(" & adduser_rol & ", " 
     & AddUser_txtDocumento.Text & ", '" & AddUser_txtNombre.Text & "', '" 
     & AddUser_txtApellido.Text & "', " & AddUser_txtContraseña.Text & ", '" 
     & AddUser_cbSexo.Text & "', '" & AddUser_dateFNacimiento.Text & "', '" 
     & AddUser_cbEstCivil.Text & "', '" & AddUser_dateFIngreso.Text & "', '" 
      & AddUser_txtCargo.Text & "', " & AddUser_cbGrado.Text & ", '" 
      & AddUser_txtDepartamento.Text & "', '" & AddUser_txtEmail.Text & "', '" 
      & AddUser_txtMailEmpresarial.Text & "', " & AddUser_txtTlfEmpresarial.Text 
      & ", '" & AddUser_txtDirCalle.Text & "', " & AddUser_txtDirNumero.Text 
      & ", '" & AddUser_txt2Nombre.Text & "', '" & AddUser_txt2apellido.Text 
      & "', 's', )"
```

Use in Vb net also Prepared statement
Like

```
cmd.Connection = conn

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO  Personal (rol, doc, nombre, apellido, passwd, sexo
                  , f_nac, estado_civil, f_ingreso, cargo, grado, dpto, email, email_empr, tlf_empr
    , calle, numero, 2nombre, 2apellido, activo) VALUES(@adduser_rol, @AddUser_txtDocumento,.....)"

cmd.Prepare()

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adduser_rol", adduser_rol)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddUser_txtDocumento", AddUser_txtDocumento.Text)
...
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Copy the insert string and try it in mysql workbench this should show an error . and use try to use prepared statement

Comment: i testet with insert into Personal (rol, doc, nombre, apellido, passwd, sexo, f_nac
    , estado_civil, f_ingreso, cargo, grado, dpto, email, email_empr, tlf_empr
    , calle, numero, 2nombre, 2apellido, activo) values(1, 1122, 'text', 'text', 1, 'text', 'text', 'text', 'text', 'text', 0, 'text', 'text', 'text', 9, 9, 'text', 's')  and it has no problems. as speculated maybe in one of your textboxes is an unwanted character **use prepared statements**

Comment: I tried the query in navicat and it works successfully, idk why in VB I have an error. As I said, I cannot use prepared statements because our teacher asked to concatenate textboxes

Comment: @GuillermoCrucci then your teacher is not a good teacher. They are teaching you to use insecure code. Are you certain that's what they really meant?

Comment: Tell me please what is the value of AddUser_txtCargo-Text?

Comment: @GuillermoCrucci Send your teacher to Stack Overflow and we will be glad to instruct him on why it is imperative to use paramatized queries and why it is never OK to concatenate text box values. This is so egregious that I implore you to unlearn this after your course is over.

Comment: @nbk You may want to check http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

Comment: @nbk I am not too familiar with `.Prepare` in MySql but it seems the query would be prepared every time this code is called. That seems to defeat the purpose. If there was a loop following this that changed the values of the parameters and called `.Execute...` then yes but not in this case. Do you need an open connection to call `.Prepare`?

Comment: Lets do it the old fashion way Remove on textbox.text after another replace them temporarily one at a time with fixed and safe Values, till you find your perpetrator. That debugging one on one

Comment: Ok I solved the problem with the INSERT statement, but i cannot solve the problem with the update, could you help me?

Comment: accept the answer, test the update string post the error message. debug it like teh last one

Comment: the error message is "Unknow colum 'i' in 'Field List' " 
I did't declare any column 'i' neither in mysql neither VB. I tried to debug the same way the last one and didn't work. Any clue?

Comment: , hijos = '" & ModUser_txtHijos.Text & "'
, tel_celular = " & ModUser_txtCelular.Text & "
, tel_fijo = " & ModUser_txtFijo.Text & "
, departamento = " & departamento.ToString & " are all not on your insert statement. check if they are in the table